# Solving $v=a^{0.5}\arctan\left(\left(\frac{1}{a}\left(M^{2}-1\right)\right)^{0.5}\right)-\arctan\left(\left(M^{2}-1\right)^{0.5}\right)$ for $M$

Tags: trigonometry

For a computer program, I am making I need this equation in terms of $M$, not $v$. (This is the Prandtl-Meyer function which I need to use to find the Match number from the Prandtl-Meyer number.)

$$v=a^{0.5}\arctan\left(\left(\frac{1}{a}\left(M^{2}-1\right)\right)^{0.5}\right)-\arctan\left(\left(M^{2}-1\right)^{0.5}\right)$$

If it's not possible to rearrange into a clean formula, alternative methods would be helpful as well as this is going to be run in a python program.

Comment: What are the ranges for $v$ and $a$?

Comment: For the sake of readability, I would suggest defining, say, 
$$b := \frac1{\sqrt{a}} \qquad x := \sqrt{M^2-1} \qquad w := bv$$
Then the relation looks much nicer:
$$w=\arctan(bx)-b\arctan x$$
and your goal is to solve for $x$ (which you would subsequently convert to $M$ via $M = \pm\sqrt{x^2+1}$).